# Azure database refdata high intermittent load

Tags: azure, paas, performance

We've been running a `SC9.1 solution` on `PAAS` for a while now, but have recently noticed intermittent slow response times, both on the CD and the CM.
We've correlated it to high load on the `refdata-db`:
[image: Refdata-db CPU]

We've looked at the analytics and there is nothing different there between the low days (<10%) and the high days (up to 100%)

Any idea's on where to look for reasons for the high loads is appreciated.

Best regards,

Rik

Comment: Hi, welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange! Have you consulted Sitecore Support with this issue yet?  There is an outstanding issue affecting caching of items in the refdata db that can lead to high db utilisation.  https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/067230

Comment: Hi @GeorgeTucker.

No I haven't consulted Sitecore Support yet, but plan to.
That issue only has a patch until 9.0, we are at 9.1
So no sure if that is still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Sitecore support and apparently it is a bug.
I have received a SQL script to execute against my refdata-db and it had a huge impact

[image: Before and after script execution]

If you also have this issue and need the scripts, contact support and reference to issue 312397.

Best regards,

Rik

Comment: The mentioned issues are related to the non-optimal implementation of GetDefinitions stored procedure.
This behavior was registered as a bug with reference number 312397.
As a workaround for the issue, please run the attached Sitecore.Support.312397.sql script against your reference data database
The modified stored procedure optimizes the process of working with reference data definitions, which eliminates the CPU issues. The update script to fix can be found here : https://gist.github.com/martinrayenglish/aba32e800618784a674eae5a3b12c5f2

Comment: All, When you execute this script in prod ref data DB, would there be any impact to website as realtime prod traffic/data can be coming into DB?

Answer (score 1):

It is a common issue which get fixed in 9.3. Please see KB from Sitecore

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/595419